# How can I change all null values with javascript before submitting to firebase firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, forms, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to allow unanswered form inputs that are not required to still be able to submit to Firebase Firestore. The issue is it returns `null is not an object`. .In case you haven't used firebase, it doesn't let you submit `null` values. I am trying to figure out how I can change all `null` value inputs to a submittable value?

Here's an example of what I am trying to do:

```
if (document.querySelector('input').value.length == 0) {
    this.value = 'No input'
  }
```

```js
document.querySelector('#feedbackForm').addEventListener('submit', e => {

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  const form = e.target
  
  const firstName = form.querySelector('#firstName').value,
    lastName = form.querySelector('#lastName').value,
    fullName = `${firstName} ${lastName}`,
    email = form.querySelector('#email').value,
    a = form.querySelector('#a:checked').value,
    b = form.querySelector('#b').value,
    c = form.querySelector('#c').value
  
  const timestamp = serverTimestamp();

  db.collection("Team Forms")
    .doc('Feedback Survey')
    .set({
      [fullName]: {
        'Name': fullName,
        'Email': email,
        'Radio 1': a,
        'Question 1': b,
        'Question 2': c,
        'Timestamp': timestamp
      }
    })

  document.querySelector('#feedbackForm')[0].reset()
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after,
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
}

form {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.basic-border {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
textarea {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

input:hover,
textarea:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  background-color: white;
  outline-offset: 0.025rem;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.radio-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.25rem;
}

.input-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

button {
  padding: 0.5rem 3rem;
  margin-inline: auto;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: gray;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<form id="feedbackForm">

  <input type="text" id="firstName" name="First Name" required placeholder="First Name" class="basic-border">
  <input type="text" id="lastName" name="Last Name" required placeholder="Last Name" class="basic-border">
  <input type="email" id="email" name="Email" required placeholder="Email" class="basic-border">

  <p>Radio 1</p>

  <div class="radio-container">
    <label for="a1">Option 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="a1" name="A" value="Value 1">
  </div>

  <div class="radio-container">
    <label for="a2">Option 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="a2" name="A" value="Value 2">
  </div>

  <div class="radio-container">
    <label for="a3">Option 3</label>
    <input type="radio" id="a3" name="A" value="Value 3">
  </div>

  <div class="input-container">
    <label for="b">Question 1</label>
    <textarea id="b" name="B" rows="5" placeholder="Your Response…" class="basic-border"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="input-container">
    <label for="c">Question 2</label>
    <input type="text" id="c" name="C" placeholder="Your Response…" class="basic-border">
  </div>

  <button class="basic-border">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Can you share code of complete form? We might be able to find best way for it

Comment: You can do this via hundreds of ways. Eg you can get all inputs inside the form and iterate through them, or just make use of the `required` attr (see my answer).

Comment: You may wish to take a look at the line 'db.collection("Team Forms").doc('Feedback Survey').set' as the error `null is not an object` suggests that the problem is in one of your objects, and not strings. But since I have not used firebase I cannot be certain, and the problem may be in the strings, as you've said. If this is the case, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you use `this` after the if statement, which is where the error is. This is because `this` refers to the window, as it is not an event. Here is what your code should look a bit li

---

```
let all_inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input"); // If you have multiple forms, use ("#form1 input");
all_inputs.forEach(input => {
   if(!input.value) {
      input.value = "No value";
   }
});
```

Furthermore, a better way to achieve this is to change the variables when you're assigning them, like so:

```
  var a = document.querySelector('[name="a"]:checked').value || "No val";
  var b = document.querySelector('[name="b"]').value || "No val";
  var c = document.querySelector('[name="c"]').value || "No val";
```

Comment: Sorry. I edited my question to make it easier to understand. I need to submit unanswered form inputs. I.E. the inputs that have .length == 0.

Comment: Ok, got it. I've edited my answer, hopeit helps.

Comment: Perhaps I implemented it wrong, but it still returned the same error. I'm not sure which part of what your code gets only the empty / null inputs to change them.

Comment: Make sure the above code is executed before the javascript in your answer. Alternatively, now that you added the js code you're using, you can use this: `'Question 1': b || 'no-val',` for each value in your object

Comment: Btw, the part of my code that gets only the empty / null inputs to change them is the if statement `!input.value`. This executes `input.value = 'no-val';` only if the `value` of the current-iteration `input` is `falsey`.

Comment: Gotcha. I tried both again. Your second option returned the same, but I put the first option above the variable setting and it gave me this error: `TypeError: all_inputs.forEach is not a function. (In 'all_inputs.forEach(input => { if(!input.value) { input.value = "null"; }})', 'all_inputs.forEach' is undefined)`

Comment: Ohhh sorry my mistake. Instead of `querySelector`, which only returns the first input, you must use `querySelectorAll`, which returns a collection of all inputs. Sorry, i mistyped!

Comment: Yeah, if my second option returned the same, then the problem is in the context of what type of data firebase wants. I suspect that the error is not in the strings, but rather in the object whose values contain these strings. Check whether your 'parent' object is valid.

Comment: Switching to `querySelectorAll` didn't seem to make a difference. The way firebase accepts the information is something I don't really understand, even though I've done as much research as I can on it.

Comment: Well, then the object/function it is! Maybe you could use their customer service if they have something like that? Or use forums exclusively for their products, if they have such forums. Good luck :).

Comment: Yeah. They have very in depth forums, but no information in them says how to solve this issue. I'll reach out to their support team though. Perhaps they can help.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I found to do was switch up how I get the values entirely.

```js
const forms = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('form'))
const output = document.querySelector('#output')

forms.forEach((formElement) => {
  formElement.addEventListener('submit', e => {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    const form = e.target,
      inputs = Array.from(form.querySelectorAll('input, textarea'))

    const data = {}

    inputs.forEach(input => {
      const {
        name,
        value,
        type,
        tagName
      } = input

      if (!value) return

      if (tagName === 'TEXTAREA' || (type && (
          type === 'text' ||
          type === 'email' ||
          type === 'tel'
        ))) return data[name] = value

      if (type && type === 'radio' && input.checked) return data[name] = value

      if (type && type === 'checkbox' && input.checked) return data[name] = [...data[name], value]
    })

    const fullName = `${data['First Name']} ${data['Last Name']}`,
      timestamp = new Date() // serverTimestamp()

    data['Full Name'] = fullName
    data['Timestamp'] = timestamp

    // Commented Firestore for demo
    // db.collection("Team Forms")
    //   .doc('Feedback Survey')
    //   .set({
    //     [fullName]: data
    //   })

    const span = document.createElement('span')

    span.innerText = JSON.stringify({
        [fullName]: data
      })
      .replaceAll(',', '\n')
      .replaceAll('{"', '{\n"')
      .replaceAll('"}', '"\n}')

    output.append(span)

    form.reset()
  })
})
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after,
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
}

form {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.basic-border {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
textarea {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

input:hover,
textarea:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  background-color: white;
  outline-offset: 0.025rem;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.radio-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.25rem;
}

.input-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

button {
  padding: 0.5rem 3rem;
  margin-inline: auto;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: gray;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
}

#output {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<form id="feedbackForm">

  <input type="text" id="firstName" name="First Name" required placeholder="First Name*" class="basic-border">
  <input type="text" id="lastName" name="Last Name" required placeholder="Last Name*" class="basic-border">
  <input type="email" id="email" name="Email" required placeholder="Email*" class="basic-border">

  <p>Radio 1</p>

  <div class="radio-container">
    <label for="a1">Option 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="a1" name="A" value="Value 1">
  </div>

  <div class="radio-container">
    <label for="a2">Option 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="a2" name="A" value="Value 2">
  </div>

  <div class="radio-container">
    <label for="a3">Option 3</label>
    <input type="radio" id="a3" name="A" value="Value 3">
  </div>

  <div class="input-container">
    <label for="b">Question 1</label>
    <textarea id="b" name="B" rows="5" placeholder="Your Response…" class="basic-border"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="input-container">
    <label for="c">Question 2</label>
    <input type="text" id="c" name="C" placeholder="Your Response…" class="basic-border">
  </div>

  <button class="basic-border">Submit</button>

</form>

<div id="output" class="basic-border"></div>
```

Using a more generic way of getting the values from inputs with the `inputs.forEach()` allows us to eliminate any null or undefined values. If needed, we could switch the `if (!value) return` to `if (!value) return data[name] = 'undefined'`